# How can I use an automatic proxy configuration in Skype?

Tags: proxy, skype, autoproxy

I'm unable to connect to Skype when I'm behind a proxy.  My organization uses an autoproxy configuration, so I don't know the name and port of my current proxy.  How can I force Skype to use my autoproxy configuration?

**Edit:**  The first thing I tried was setting up *Automatic Proxy Detection* in the Advanced Options.  This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Connection.

Select **Automatic proxy detection**.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a [.pac file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config#The_PAC_file) in Internet Explorer's cache.  The .pac file can hold rules the browser to use to decide which proxy to use.  You could attempt to use those proxies directly, or if they require authentication you could try formatting the proxy setting with your credentials similar to this `username:password@ipaddress:port`.

That said, corporations can detect and block Skype traffic with packet inspection, and I've heard of many corporations dismissing people violating the corporate policies.  Just had the throw that in there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Where I work we can use the corporate-approved version of Skype, so the packets can go through anyway.